# SQL select values on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table similar to the following:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| instance_id | product_id | option_value_id |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
|           1 |          1 |               1 |
|           1 |          1 |               2 |
|           1 |          1 |               3 |
|           2 |          1 |               1 |
|           2 |          1 |               3 |
|           2 |          1 |               4 |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
```

How would I create a query to find that instance_id 2 represents an instance of product_id 1 that has option values 1,3 and 4?

For example, I'd like to be able to query the table something like as follows:

`select instance_id from instances where product_id = 1 'having' option_value_id = 1 and option_value_id=3 and option_value_id=4` (obviously this won't actaully work) and get the result

```
+-------------+
| instance_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
```

Any help or pointers much appreciated

Comment: It might add clarity to your question if you define how you want the resulting data to look. _As the simple query seems totally obvious_

Comment: updated question to include an example that hopefully explains what I'm on about a bit better.

Comment: Can you try `select instance_id where instance_id=2 and (option_value_id=1 or option_value_id=3 or option_value_id=4)`

Comment: but i don't know before hand that instance_id=2. That is what I need to find out given the option_value_ids (1,3,4) that i do know

Comment: Ah! Then my comment before doesn't help you...

Answer (score 0):

would help to know what your desired output would be... but perhaps something like:

```
Select A.Instannce_ID, B.instance_ID, group_concat(Distinct option_value_ID SEPERATOR ',') as Option_Values
from Table A
INNER JOIn table B
 on A.Product_ID = B.Product_ID 
and A.Instance_ID < B.Instance_ID
WHERE Option_value_ID In (1,3,4)
GROUP BY  A.Instannce_ID, B.instance_ID
HAVING Count(distinct option_value_ID) = 3
```

This does a self join on the product_ID ensuring that the instances don't match and we don't get two way matches, and reports the option values in 1 field.

Comment: Is there a way to query by the options. ie. I want to know which instance has (and only has) options 1,3,4

Comment: by adding a group by having and a where in list; this can be done.  I added details above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id
     , group_concat(option_value_id) 
  from table 
  where instance_id = 1 
  group by instance_id;
```

Obviously won't get what you want if product_id changes *within* instance_id, i.e. you could have multiple product_ids per instance_id. I don't know the schema but the above should get you started.